# Hotkeys are not working on Asus Laptop

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, services, asus-laptop

I'm unable to use my function keys on Asus Laptop after cleaning up the registry and turning off some excessive services. I assume I turned off some wrong service and I am unable to use <kbd>**Fn**</kbd> keys.

In particular <kbd>**Fn**</kbd>+<kbd>**F3**</kbd>, <kbd>**Fn**</kbd>+<kbd>**F4**</kbd>, <kbd>**Fn**</kbd>+<kbd>**F7**</kbd> and <kbd>**Fn**</kbd>+<kbd>**F9**</kbd>.

Other Shortcuts are operational (Fn+F1,2,5,6,8,10,11,12).
The Keys F3, F4... do work in applications but do not work with Fn.

> What I tried to remedy this problem:
>
> 1. Reinstalled the official drivers and ASUS Hot Keys application;
> 2. Set the official driver on startup -
>    I can't complete this step for some reason.
>    Once I reboot the task manager all the changes get wiped out.
>    Checked if the drivers for my keyboard are installed via Device Manager. They were. I also connected and disconnected the keyboard just to see if it's the case;
> 3. Used Windows Troubleshooter in system settings

Asus hotkey application -
[image: Asus hotkey application]

Process that has to run in the background at startup but cannot be enabled -
[image: startup process that has to run on the background but cannot be enabled]

Answer (score 1):

This Service in windows Services was the issue: "ASLDR Service"

If someone comes across this problem just right-click 
windows icon choose services and find the one from the picture above

Answer (score 0):

Check for solutions here:

https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-fn-keys-on-my-asus-laptop-not-working/

The first solution on there solved my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit you answer to add a summary from the link.  Links can disappear, making this answer useless.